# How does the record assembly work in dremel?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, fsm, finite-state-automaton, dremel

I was referring to the white paper of [dremel](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36632.pdf).

I was able to understand the record spitting, but the finite state machine(fsm) generation from the spitted records is  a bit confusing. Can anyone explain how the records are assembled back?

Images:

[Schema, record spitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYxj6.png)

[Record assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLVaS.png)

I tried checking out materials/ blogs for same but I was unable to find relevant resources.